# Provenance of a result on regular simplices with integer vertices

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

There are several MO questions related to the question of characterizing those integers $n$ for which there exists a regular $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with integer vertices, e.g., [coordinates of vertices of regular simplex](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38724) and [For which $n$ is there a regular $n$-simplex with vertices in $\mathbb{Z}^n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278775/for-which-n-is-there-a-regular-n-simplex-with-vertices-in-mathbbzn). I would like to know where this result originally appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my own question. The reference is I. J. Schoenberg, Regular simplices and quadratic forms, *J. London Math. Soc.* **12** (1937), 48-55.